# How to solve error filter_mailchimp_campaign plugin does not exist?

Tags: 8, emails

I have a D8 website which gives a error:

```
Er is onverwacht een fout opgetreden. Probeer het later nog eens.</br></br><em class="placeholder">Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException</em>: The &quot;filter_mailchimp_campaign&quot; plugin does not exist. in <em class="placeholder">Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager-&gt;doGetDefinition()</em> (line <em class="placeholder">52</em> of <em class="placeholder">core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Discovery/DiscoveryTrait.php</em>). <pre class="backtrace">Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager-&gt;getDefinition(&#039;filter_mailchimp_campaign&#039;) (Line: 70)
Drupal\filter\FilterPluginCollection-&gt;initializePlugin(&#039;filter_mailchimp_campaign&#039;) (Line: 80)
Drupal\Component\Plugin\LazyPluginCollection-&gt;get(&#039;filter_mailchimp_campaign&#039;) (Line: 26)
Drupal\filter\FilterPluginCollection-&gt;get(&#039;filter_mailchimp_campaign&#039;) (Line: 91)
Drupal\filter\FilterPluginCollection-&gt;sortHelper(&#039;filter_mailchimp_campaign&#039;, &#039;filter_align&#039;)
uasort(Array, Array) (Line: 90)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultLazyPluginCollection-&gt;sort() (Line: 84)
Drupal\filter\FilterPluginCollection-&gt;sort() (Line: 137)
Drupal\filter\Entity\FilterFormat-&gt;filters() (Line: 149)
Drupal\filter\Entity\FilterFormat-&gt;getPluginCollections() (Line: 357)
Drupal\Core\Config\Entity\ConfigEntityBase-&gt;__sleep()
serialize(Array) (Line: 240)
Drupal\Core\Cache\DatabaseBackend-&gt;doSetMultiple(Array) (Line: 193)
Drupal\Core\Cache\DatabaseBackend-&gt;setMultiple(Array) (Line: 181)
Drupal\Core\Cache\DatabaseBackend-&gt;set(&#039;filter_formats:nl&#039;, Array, -1, Array) (Line: 107)
filter_formats(Object) (Line: 131)
Drupal\filter\Element\TextFormat::processFormat(Array, Object, Array)
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 993)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder-&gt;doBuildForm(&#039;node_page_edit_form&#039;, Array, Object) (Line: 1056)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder-&gt;doBuildForm(&#039;node_page_edit_form&#039;, Array, Object) (Line: 1056)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder-&gt;doBuildForm(&#039;node_page_edit_form&#039;, Array, Object) (Line: 1056)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder-&gt;doBuildForm(&#039;node_page_edit_form&#039;, Array, Object) (Line: 557)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder-&gt;processForm(&#039;node_page_edit_form&#039;, Array, Object) (Line: 314)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder-&gt;buildForm(&#039;node_page_edit_form&#039;, Object) (Line: 74)
Drupal\Core\Controller\FormController-&gt;getContentResult(Object, Object)
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 123)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber-&gt;Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}() (Line: 582)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer-&gt;executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 124)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber-&gt;wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext(Array, Array) (Line: 97)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber-&gt;Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}() (Line: 151)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel-&gt;handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 68)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel-&gt;handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session-&gt;handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle-&gt;handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 99)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache-&gt;pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 78)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache-&gt;handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware-&gt;handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 50)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware-&gt;handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel-&gt;handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 664)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel-&gt;handle(Object) (Line: 19)
</pre>
```

I tried several solutions like uninstall all , reinstall with devel 
but none of this is working.

Any suggestion how to proceed?

Comment: Since it shouldn't be possible when uninstalling properly, sounds like you removed the module that provides that filter plugin without uninstalling it. Never do that.

Answer (score 1):

Can be solved by:

I was able to fix this. I had to go into the database and manually delete the entry "filter.mailchimp_campaing" from the config table.